# too and either usage differences

Tags: adverbs, adverbial-phrases

> A: I don't like oranges.
>
> B: I don't like oranges **either**.

This is the right way to express this idea.

question 1: But why can't it be written like this:

> B: I **too** don't like oranges.

question 2: What is the actual meaning of this???

Comment: It can be written like that. You could also write *I also …* It's not quite clear exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, in principle:

First example: Either -

> I don't like apples and I don't like oranges either.

The speaker is stating that s/he doesn't like either apples or oranges.

Second example: Too

A: >I don't like oranges.
B: >I too don't like oranges.

Speaker B is agreeing with Speaker A that s/he doesn't like oranges.

In practice, many people would say **I don't like oranges either** to agree with someone else that **I too don't like oranges**.

**I too** may sound a bit too highfalutin but it's the best way of making things clear, that the **too** refers to the speaker and not to the oranges.

https://englishhelponline.me/2010/06/01/the-difference-between-words-too-and-eitherneither/

Comment: Is "I don't like oranges too" also correct? and same as "I don't like oranges either" ?

Comment: The meaning would depend on the context - what the too was referring to. It's not clear without context.